# In css, how do I position a list of images, so that each one is right and down of it's previous sibling?

Tags: html, css, position

I have the following mockup html:

```
<img />
<img />
<img />
<img />
```

I want each image positioned 10px down, and 10px to the right of it's previous image. It needs to look like the Result in https://jsfiddle.net/f0c429sq/1/.

I managed to get the correct result in that jsfiddle link by having each img nested deeper, and using `position: absolute`, like the following.

```
<div>
    <img />
    <div>
        <img />
        <div>
            <img />
            <div>
                <img />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But that's really ugly, and it doesn't work in my case, because I'm using AngularJS, and the list of images will be made using `ng-repeat`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/rpjyewm8/

```
<div class="image-stack">
  <img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
  <img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
  <img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
  <img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
  <img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
</div>

.image-stack .image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.image-stack .image:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.image-stack .image:nth-child(2) {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.image-stack .image:nth-child(3) {
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}

.image-stack .image:nth-child(4) {
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}

.image-stack .image:nth-child(5) {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

And if you are using Sass, you can do it in a loop:

```
.image-stack {

  .image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    @for $image from 1 through 5 {
      &:nth-child(#{$image}) {
        top: ($image * 10) + px;
        left: ($image * 10) + px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks great. I didn't know about nth-child.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should do it, hope it's what you're looking for:

```
<style>
.a { padding-left:10px;margin-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-bottom:10px;
.b { padding-left:20px;margin-left:20px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-bottom:10px;
.c { padding-left:30px;margin-left:30px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-bottom:10px;
</style>
<img src="1.jpg class="a" /><br>
<img src="2.jpg class="b" /><br>
<img src="3.jpg class="c" /><br>
```

Comment: First of all... you should NEVER be using inline css.  Secondly... you should NEVER be using line-breaks for positioning.  This is just bad all around.